# > library(ez) Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ez’ in loadNamespace

Tags: r

```
> library(ez)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ez’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘zip’

Comment: have you tried installing the package `zip` which the error says is missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the zip package manually and it will work.

```
install.packages("zip")
install.packages("ez")

library(ez)
```

> Warning message:
>   Paket ‘ez’ wurde unter R Version 3.5.3 erstellt

Should work!